# Custom Element Directives and attributes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service, angularjs-directive, attributes

**myPage.html**

```
<div ng-controller="MyPageCtrl">
    <my-custom-directive arg1="{{currentObj.name}}"></my-custom-directive>
<div>
```

in **myPageCtrl.js (Controller)**

```
app.controller("MyPageCtrl", ["$scope", function ($scope) {
          $scope.currentObj = {"name":"Collin"};
    }]);
```

And this is how my directive code looks like

```
app.directive("myCustomDirective", [function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        controller: "MyCustomDirCtrl"
    };
}]);
```

Finally here's my directive's controller,

```
app.controller("MyCustomDirCtrl", ["$attrs", function ($attrs) {
      var arg = $attrs.arg1;
      alert('Arg '+arg);
}]);
```

The alert just displays "{{currentObj.name}}" and not the value of the name property of currentObj.

Please can you suggest me ways to figure this out.

Thanks.

Comment: Where are you setting currentObj.name?

Comment: I've modified the question a bit... Hope you can help me in this regard...

Comment: Why are you using a directive if you are trying to access the attributes from your controller?

Comment: Actually the directive does other works too. Based on the name I perform other operations. All I want is the value of currentObj.name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why did you use $attrs for a controller. Just use a normal $scope.

**myPage.html**

```
<div ng-controller="MyPageCtrl">
    <my-custom-directive arg1="{{currentObj.name}}"></my-custom-directive>
<div>
```

**myPageCtrl.js (Controller)**

```
app.controller("MyPageCtrl", ["$scope", function ($scope) {
          $scope.currentObj = {"name":"Collin"};
    }]);
```

**myCustomDirective**

```
app.directive("myCustomDirective", [function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        controller: "MyCustomDirCtrl"
    };
}]);
```

**Directive's controller** (change $attrs to $scope here),

```
app.controller("MyCustomDirCtrl", ["$scope", function ($scope) {
      var arg = $scope.arg1;
      alert('Arg '+arg);
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of accessing the attr from your controller, you could access it from your directive using the link function.

```
app.directive("myCustomDirective", [function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        controller: "MyCustomDirCtrl",
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {
            alert(attr.arg1);
        }
    };
}]);
```